# Printing values of int arrays

Tags: java, arrays

I'm currently trying to understand how int arrays work so here's a code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] name;
    name = new int[] {10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100};
    System.out.println(name);
}
```

My problem is that it prints out `[I@15b7986` in Eclipse. I'm curious to understand why and perhaps find a way to print out those number values in the integer array.

Answer (score 1):

The "[I@15b7986" is the result of the toString() method on the array, which isn't helpful for viewing the elements in the array.  Depending on what you are trying to accomplish, maybe something like this will help...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] name = new int[]{10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100};
    System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(name));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

System.out.println() calls object.toString() implicitly which Java documentation will default to:

```
getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
```

See: 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html

To print the list of values in the array you would want to call:

```
StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
for (int x : name) {
   out.append(x);
   out.append(" ");
}
System.out.println(out.toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using java 8 you could execute the following:

```
int[] name = new int[]{10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100};

Arrays.stream(name).forEach(p -> System.out.println(p));
```